# PHP How can I store variables in an array and call them

Tags: php, arrays, variables

Ok so yesterday I was working on a PHP API all day (2:30PM - 3:30AM CT). 
The user/client/front end of the API can submit a filename or link to the API so it can view it, edit it, or delete it.

But that's a problem because if the user can do that that means they could edit or delete the website with the client.

So I'm wondering can I store a bunch of variables that are equal to links, so when the client submits, the API will see if that link is unauthorized or authorized

Could you do it like this

```
<?php
$myArray = array( //Unauthorized Links 
    $link1 => "http://example.com" //First Link
);
?>
```

Then check the links using $myArray?

If you need the API code I'll provide it.

Comment: Use quotes in string values in array

Comment: @Rishi Ok sorry bout that got in a rush, but problem still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code and it will work for you

```
<?php
    $myArray = array(
        1 => 'http://example-1.com',
        2 => 'http://example-2.com',
        3 => 'http://example-3.com',
        4 => 'http://example-4.com'
    );

    foreach($myArray as $key => $value){
        echo 'link '.$key.' = '.$value.' <br>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: link1 in on line 1 Notice: Undefined variable: link2 in on line 1 Notice: Undefined variable: link3 in on line 1 Notice: Undefined variable: link4 in on line 1 Notice: Undefined variable: linkn in on line 1 link = http://example-1.com  link = http://example-2.com  link = http://example-3.com  link = http://example-4.com  link = http://example-n.com

Comment: @abrad1212; sorry it's my fault, test it now

Comment: Thanks the links are being displayed! Now I'm going to integrate this with my API I'll DM you if I can't get it working. :)

Comment: **Ok so would doing something like this work?** `} elseif (isset($_POST['filename']) and $_POST['filename'] == $Links)    {      die("Sorry you may not access that link");   }` **Because I'm trying it and right now it's not working**

Comment: Ok I think I isolated my problem from the previous comment, my problem is that foreach has the $value and I'm needing to use that throughout the whole script! Should I just put it on top of the script and close it at the bottom? So i can use $value throughout the whole script.